# SQL table join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, query-optimization

I have these two SQL queries at the top of every page on my site:

```
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id='$user_ID'", $db); 
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result);

$level  = $rs['level'];
$name   = $rs['name'];  

$sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE name='$name'", $db);
$rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2); 

if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result2) == 0) {
  header("Location: dead.php");
}

// get data
```

First off it checks the accounts table to see if the player has an account. If he does, it checks if he has a player from members. If there isn't a record found, he's been killed.

Is this ok as it is? Or could i speed up things by making it one query?

I'm not sure how to go about it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should be one query. A `JOIN` is pretty straightforward here:

```
SELECT members.*, accounts.level, accounts.name FROM members
  JOIN accounts ON members.name = accounts.name
 WHERE accounts.id = '$user_ID';
```

Make sure `accounts.name` is indexed, however. An alternative would be to add an `account_id` column to `members` and join on that instead since presumably `accounts.id` is already indexed.

Comment: accounts.id is set as PRIMARY, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, `PRIMARY` keys are automatically indexed.

Comment: Alright. I went through my tables indexing columns that I thought were the logical ones- 'player_id's, 'to_id' in the mails one, etc. Might be an illusion but it seems to be running a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with join you can use "SELECT . FROM  WHERE . = .". Your code would probably look something like "SELECT accounts.*, members.* FROM accounts, members WHERE accounts.memberID = members.memberID". Of course, I'm assuming your members table has an id column.